# what's the line meaning in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

the link:

http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4410#comment:2

RECOMMENDATIONS:

> Consider making the post link clickable in case the user does not
>   make a post title.

what's  meaning of the above line? thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Consider making the post link clickable /*as the post entry*/ in case the user does not make a post title /*which should be made as the entry*/.`

Comment: i am sorry, i am still not follow it well.

Comment: @zhuanzhou,usually we click the post title to get into a post and read it.But WP allows publishing non-title post,in situation like this,it'll be difficult to enter the post if the post link is not clickable.

Comment: i tried to publish an entry without title. and changed the theme to the default twenty, there is also no title and not clickable to the entry when i view the home page.

Comment: and in my theme, the post title is clickable .i don't know why the theme review team gave me the RECOMMENDATIONS.

Comment: @zhuanzhou,that's why this is called  `RECOMMENDATIONS`.

Comment: i know i could not alter the RECOMMENDATIONS part. but i want to know why they recommended me? and in  my theme, the entry title  is clickable. could you do a test and have a check to my theme? thank you.

Comment: I tried the your theme and it's fine.I've no idea why the recommendation is given.Maybe you can send an EMAIL to get the detail information.

Comment: @zhuanzhou let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1400/discussion-between-spawncxy-and-zhuanzhou)

Answer (score 0):

Post link in your theme must be clickable, that is it must take user to add new post

Comment: i am sorry, i am still not follow it well.in wordpress, the vistor can't add a new post. could you make an example. thank you

Comment: sorry not new post, they can add reply or comment only if the added post title are clickable. post title can take the user to the actual post page there the user can add comment only if the post title are clickable

Comment: in my theme, the post title is clickable .could you do a test to it, thank you.i don't know why the theme review team gave me the RECOMMENDATIONS